# How to Draw Shapes with Fill from Curves outside a Pythagorean Triangle?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to create this, the curve is basically perhaps just a $\sin(3x) + \log(2x)$ or similar function like that, all curves located outside each sides of triangles. With each curve will have area with different filled color.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The `\pic`s were made just for this. If you create a `\pic` with the desired shape then you can draw it wherever you want, adjusting size, rotation angle, colors, etc.

This in an example with an approximate shape (you can change my definition for the function you suggest or whatever you need):

```tex
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\tikzset
{%
   pics/my shape/.style n args={7}{% #1=base lenght,        #2=node (inside),
                                   % #3=node (below left),  #4=node (below center),
                                   % #5=node (below right), #6=node (above right),  
      code={%
        \begin{scope}[scale=#1]
          % shape
          \path[pic actions] (0,0)      to[out=75,in=180] (0.225,0.4) to[out=0,in=180]
                             (0.55,0.2) to[out=0,in=180]  (0.75,0.25) to[out=0,in=105] (1,0) -- cycle;
          % nodes
          \node at (0.5 ,0.1)      {$#2$};
          \node at (0   ,-0.25/#1) {\strut$#3$};
          \node at (0.5 ,-0.25/#1) {\strut$#4$};
          \node at (1   ,-0.25/#1) {\strut$#5$};
          \node at (0.75,0.325)    {\strut$#6$};
        \end{scope}
    }},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round]
% triangle lengths
\def\aa{3}
\def\bb{4}
\pgfmathsetmacro\cc{sqrt(\aa*\aa+\bb*\bb)}
% angle (hypotenuse)
\pgfmathsetmacro\dd{atan(\aa/\bb)}
% triangle
\pic[rotate=\dd,draw=cyan, fill=cyan!30,text=cyan] at (0,0)     {my shape={\cc}{C}{}{c}{}{}};
\pic[rotate=-90,draw=black,fill=gray!30]           at (\dd:\cc) {my shape={\aa}{A}{}{a}{}{}};
\pic[rotate=180,draw=cyan, fill=cyan!50,text=cyan] at (\bb,0)   {my shape={\bb}{B}{}{b}{}{}};
% right angle 
\draw (\bb-0.25,0) |-++ (0.25,0.25);
% shapes
\pic[draw=cyan, fill=cyan!30,text=cyan] at (0,-4) {my shape={\cc}{C}{0}{}{c}{y=f(x)}};
\pic[draw=black,fill=gray!30]           at (0,-6) {my shape={\aa}{A}{0}{}{a}{y=g(x)}};
\pic[draw=cyan, fill=cyan!50,text=cyan] at (0,-8) {my shape={\bb}{B}{0}{}{b}{y=h(x)}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]